# Is there an option to disable drag & drop feature in LibreOffice Draw?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

I faced an issue for using LibreOffice Draw.
I need to move images between grid points snapping to them.
But when I hold the images for more than 1 second, it automatically switched to free transform mode (drag & drop, also the mouse cursor would to be changed).
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you move the image a bit after clicking on it, the mode will not switch. That's at least how it works here.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can simply do it by disabling this from settings but here you need to move the image for a second just after clicking on it. I think this is the only way to solve your issue.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail about the settings?
And is there any way that we can disable it by extension?

Comment: May I know in which system you are right now ? Linux , Mac or Windows ?

Comment: Windows 10 64bit

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and [this version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1weDxMJlHw1GjeaYAC7wTrOJuB1QKoUPB/view?usp=sharing) of **LibreOffice Draw** . I haven't faced such problem like you, Used windows only for 1-2 months only , so haven't any idea, still I think you have better alternative available of **LibreOffice Draw** on Windows. However, share me what exact problem you are facing so I can forward that to my friends who are using windows. And if they can solve then I will let you know.